# notepad++ and swapping two values

Tags: regex, notepad++

So I need to swap 2 values across multiple files. These are hex color values which are #4f225a and #ed2028. How would I use regular expression to swap these values?

Basically, I need to change #4f225a to #ed2028 and **vice versa**.

Comment: it cannot be done in one go..you require one substitution and two replacement

Comment: 3 passes. #4f225a = Tmp, #ed2028 = #4f225a , Tmp = #ed2028

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dumb and easy way :

1. replace each occurrence of string1 by a specific token you will find nowhere else in your file
2. replace each occurence of string2 by string1
3. replace each occurence of the specific token by string2

Comment: Ah I gotcha so do a find and replace of #4f225a to #ed2028a. And then do a find and replace of #ed2028 (exact match) with #4f225a. Lastly, go back and switch #ed2028a with #ed2028. That makes sense and yes, dumb and easy. thanks